# I keep getting this Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to commit to batch but I keep getting this error but cant figure out where i am going wrong, i tried moving the batch outside certain functions but still not progress, here is my code,i am not sure what I'm missing , i keep getting this error :

```
scheduledFunction
Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.
    at WriteBatch.verifyNotCommitted (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:117:19)
    at WriteBatch.update (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:313:14)
    at /workspace/index.js:152:48
    at QuerySnapshot.forEach (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:748:22)
    at step2 (/workspace/index.js:91:39)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

here is my code

```
async function updateBets() {
var marketRef = db.collection('matches');
var snapshot = await marketRef.where('matchStatus', '==', 'FINISHED').get();





if (snapshot.empty) {
    console.log('No matching documents.');
    return;


}



console.log('I found documents');


snapshot.forEach(doc => {



    if (doc.data().matchId == null) {


        //console.log('document with error" ' + doc.id);


    }



    step2();



    async function step2() {


        if (doc.data().matchId != null) {

            var query = doc.data().matchId.toString();
            // console.log('here is match ID' + query);


            var marketRef2 = db.collection('markets');
            var snapshot2 = await marketRef2.where('marketId', '==', query).get();



            snapshot2.forEach(doc2 => {


                if (doc2.data().marketTitleId == 'FULL_TIME_RESULT') {



                    var a = doc.data().homeTeamScore;
                    var b = doc.data().awayTeamScore;



                    var winnerIndex;


                    if (a > b) {


                        winnerIndex = 0;

                        var resultIndex = ['WINNER', 'LOSER', 'LOSER'];

                        var docName = `${doc.data().matchId}` + '000' + '1';


                        var sfRef = db.collection('markets').doc(docName);
                        batch5.update(sfRef, {
                            results: resultIndex
                        });



                    } else if (a == b) {


                        winnerIndex = 1;

                        var docName = `${doc.data().matchId}` + '000' + '1';


                        var resultIndex = ['LOSER', 'WINNER', 'LOSER'];

                        var sfRef = db.collection('markets').doc(docName);
                        batch5.update(sfRef, {
                            results: resultIndex
                        });



                    } else if (a < b) {


                        winnerIndex = 2;

                        var docName = `${doc.data().matchId}` + '000' + '1';



                        var resultIndex = ['LOSER', 'LOSER', 'WINNER'];

                        var sfRef = db.collection('markets').doc(docName);
                        batch5.update(sfRef, {
                            results: resultIndex
                        });


                    }

                }



            })


        }




    }




});


try {
    await batch5.commit();
    console.log("im done with results");
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Mac! there was an error with results: ', err);
}


}
```

.....................................................................................................

Answer (score 2):

Your main function is an async which will continue to run all methods asynchronously, ignoring any internal functions. You must make sure that all jobs being applied to the batch are added before attempting to commit, at the core this is a race condition.

You can handle these multiple ways, such as wrapping it with a promise chain or creating a callback.
For a callback, add the following before your `forEach`

```js
var itemsProcessed = 0;
```

Insert this at the end of the forEach

```js
    itemsProcessed++;
    if(itemsProcessed === array.length) {
      CommitBatch();
    }
```

Then put your batch.commit() method inside this callback function

```js
function CommitBatch(){
    try {
        await batch5.commit();
        console.log("im done with results");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Mac! there was an error with results: ', err);
    }
}
```